# How to filter a list of String down to a distinct list made of string suffices in Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java streams but need to master by practice really!

The collection input is made up of strings e.g. `[name][dot][country]`, example as follows:

```
JAMES.BRITAIN
JOHN.BRITAIN
LEE.BRITAIN
GEORGE.FRANCE
LEON.FRANCE
MARSELLE.FRANCE
KOFI.GHANA
CHARLIE.GHANA
```

Please, how do I return a list of unique countries in a single stream statement?

Expected result will be a **distinct** list as follows:

```
BRITAIN
FRANCE
GHANA
```

In the real code the streams statement below gives me the list to be filtered i.e.:

```java
List<String> allSolrCollections =  (List<String>) findAllCollections()
    .getJsonArray(SOLR_CLOUD_COLLECTION)
    .getList()
    .stream() 
    .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative solution**

You can use the advantage of the method `Pattern#splitAsStream(CharSerquence)`. Once you split each line into a new Stream, skip the first item, `flatMap` the result into a new Stream and produce a `Set`.

```java
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.");

final Set<String> result = list.stream()
        .flatMap(string -> pattern.splitAsStream(string).skip(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

> ```
> [GHANA, FRANCE, BRITAIN]
> ```

Comment: Brilliant Solution. Thanks Nikolas. Please, can someone share a good resource for learning the basics and nuances of Java 8 streams. I meet it everywhere even at interviews!

Comment: It would sound ridiculous, but most of the Stream API I have learned was from answering questions here :D ... which included trying it out in the IDE, and reading some JavaDocs. Using at least Java 8 in the work also does not hurt. I have also learned a lot from reading the answers here.

Comment: That makes absolute sense Nikolas. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

- for the first part of problem, you need to convert each entry to corresponding country. so, you could use `String.split` function and keep the country part.
- for the second part you could take advantage of the `Stream.distinct` function that will remove duplicates from incoming stream.

finally, this should work:

```java
List<String> res = list.stream()
        .map(s -> s.split("\\.")[1])
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Java 16 now has a `Stream.toList` method so the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is no longer necessary.

Comment: @sprinter `Stream.toList` will give the `immutable list` and `.collect(Collectors.toList())` will give the `mutable list`. So incase if there is some manipulation needed in the list, it will break in case of `Stream.toList`. So, it will depend on the further conditions of the code. If no manipulation --> Stream.toList else --> .collect(Collectors.toList()).

Comment: @girdhar that's not correct. `Collectors.toList()` does not guarantee mutability. Specifically from the doc: "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier)."

Comment: @sprinter, yes you are right. Actually my point is we cannot directly replace the Stream.toList with the Collectors.toList() as the `Stream.toList` will always gives us the `immutable list`. So it will depend on the use-case of the list.

Comment: @Mahdi - I love your thinking and how you have simplified what seems a complex logic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, can someone share a good resource for learning the basics and nuances of Java 8 streams. I meet it everywhere even at interviews!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be careful about format it would be worth using a regular expression. This also makes the meaning of the code clearer to a reader.

```
Pattern inputPattern = Pattern.compile("- (?<name>[A-Z]+)\\.(?<country>[A-Z]+)");
list.stream()
    .map(inputPattern::match)
    .filter(Matcher::matches)
    .map(m -> m.group("country"))
    .distinct()
    .toList();
```

This ignores lines that don't match the expected format.

Comment: Wow, excellent logic. Especially being able to filter out unwanted items. So cool.

Comment: Please, can someone share a good resource for learning the basics and nuances of Java 8 streams. I meet it everywhere even at interviews!